# How to manage read-only files that don't have to be updated using React+Flux

Tags: reactjs, flux

I'm using React-Flux on an app I'm working on and I've hit a wall, so I have to make sure that so far I'm using everything properly.

I have a json file that is only for reading purposes. It should never change dynamically. I'm getting the file data from an Ajax request I'm performing in my AppActions file. So far so good. Now I'm trying to use the stored data. My question is this: In the AppStore file should I add an emitChange event to the corresponding case? How should I manage read-only files?

This whole thing came up when I tried to use the data in a component I was building and if I wasn't using an event listener inside the `componentWillMount` and `componentWillUnmount` functions I couldn't get the stored data every time I refreshed the page.

```
const AppStore = new AppStoreClass();
AppStore.dispatchToken = AppDispatcher.register(action =>{
 switch(action.actionType){
  case AppConstants.GET_NAMES:
   setNames(action.names);
   AppStore.emitChange();
   break;
 }
});
export default AppStore;
```

This is the `Nameday` component where I use the read-only data.

```
class Nameday extends Component {
 constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = {
   saints: AppStore.getNames(),
  }
  this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
 }

 componentWillMount(){
  AppStore.addChangeListener(this.onChange);
 }
 componentDidMount(){
  AppActions.getNames();
 } 
 onChange(){
  this.setState({
   saints: AppStore.getNames(),
  });
 }
 componentWillUnmount(){
  AppStore.removeChangeListener(this.onChange);
 }

 render() {
  let dates = [];
   this.state.saints.map((saint, i) => {
    saint.names.map((name, j) => {
     if (name === firstName) {
      dates.push(saint.date);
     }
     return dates;
    });
    return null;
   });
  let option = ....
  return (
   option
  );
 }
}
```